# MySQL Using ST_CONTAINS to obtain points within a bounding box

Tags: geometry, mysql, spatial-query

Can someone give me an insight into why the following MySQL code is not working.  I have taken some of this code from [this link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118053/how-to-know-if-a-point-is-inside-a-rectangle-on-the-map) and it is all about just proving the concept before applying to my site.  What I want to do is find the points on a line that are bounded by a polygon.

The line is defined by:

```
LINESTRING (-4 5,5 5,10 5,12 5)
```

and is entered into the mySQL new_table row new_tablecol as a BLOB.   If I inspect the field it is consistent with the LINESTRING above.

I now have defined a bounding box and SQL using the following syntax:

```
SET @g1 = GeomFromText('Polygon(0 0, 10 0, 10 10, 10 0, 0 0)');
SELECT * FROM `new_table` WHERE ST_CONTAINS(`new_tablecol`,@g1)
```

Clearly the bounding box includes some of the LINESTRING, but no matter how hard I manipulate this I can't get any points returned.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone having the same problem - the answer is that an incorrect syntax was being using for the POLYGON declaration.   The POLYGON should have been declared using the following method:

```
 SET @g1 = ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('POLYGON((175 150, 20 40, 50 60, 125 100, 175 150))');
```

Notice the double brackets around the POLYGON coordinate enteries.

Answer (score 1):

> Clearly the bounding box includes **some** of the LINESTRING, but no
>   matter how hard I manipulate this I can't get any points returned.

`ST_CONTAINS` returns true only if one feature contains the other. So the polygon has to include *of the LineString to be returned. But in your LineString, the first point `(-4 5)` is outside the box.

Comment: Is there anyway around this, as on a map with lots of LINESTRING routes, the bounding box would have to be impractically large?

Comment: @TrueBlue It depends on your objectives. Have you looked at other spatial predicates such as ST_Intersects(), ST_Overlaps and so on? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/spatial-relation-functions-object-shapes.html

Comment: For anyone wanting to know the solution.   Polygons return a null for most of these tests.  You just define a polygon using LINESTRING.